# How to create this layout in Ionic3

Tags: css, ionic2, flexbox, ionic3, css-grid

I would like to create the layout bellow, I have tried to use css `padding: 0;`  but I still get some padding and margin. The second Image is what I am getting.
code for the layout

```
<ion-content class="home">
  <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <img src="assets/Instrumentitem1.png" alt="">
          <p>Bass</p>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row >
        <ion-col>
          <img src="assets/Instrumentitem2.png" alt="">
          <p>Cello</p>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <img src="assets/Instrumentitem3.png" alt="">
          <p>Viola</p>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

For my styling this is what I have done. I also had tried removing padding and margin on the image but I got the same results.

```
    .home{
       scroll-content{
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
       }
    ion-grid{
         padding: 0;
    }
    ion-row{
       flex: 1;
    }
    img{  
    }
    p{
     position: absolute;
     color: white;
     font-size: 3em;
     font-weight: bold;
     top: 10%;
     right: 20%;
    } 
   }
```

[image: Scree One what I woollike to achive]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `no-padding` attribute on the grid element, like this:

```
<ion-grid no-padding>...</ion-grid>
```

Since it...

> Removes padding from the grid and immediate children columns.

You can find more information in **[Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#grid-attributes).**

Comment: Can help me fix this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128929/tabs-not-showing-after-changing-the-rootpage-in-ionic3.